# Java software that creates an adjacency matrix for you?

Tags: java, graphs, algorithms

Is there a program where you can enter a 2d array or draw a graph and it will create an adjacency matrix for you?

Comment: What do you mean by 2d array? Already the adjacency matrix? What is the expected outcome here?

Comment: Do you want a GUI program? If command-line only, what is your input?